# Python way around 128 if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, tkinter, checkbox

I have a tkinter application I am working on which has button which when pressed fires a function. I also have about 7 checkboxs which when checked changes its own variable from 0 to 1.

In the function I have a bunch of if statements that goes through every combination of the checkboxes and performs and action. The issue is because the checkbox can have two states, off (0) and on (1) with 7 checkboxes - if we do 2 to the power of 7 to work out every single combination, that is 128 if statements I will need to write out.

I have also thought about writing 7 if statement to check each state of each checkbox then moving onto the next one but because I need to loop through a 2 lists and perform different actions, it's hard to log what is happening at each stage without duplication of logs or the detail I need.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Example of one of the if statements

```
if 'PId' in df and 'CId' in df:
        for i, w in zip(df['CId'], df['PId']):
            if varsd.get() == 1 and varad.get() == 1 and vared.get() == 0 
            and varcn.get() == 0
            and varpn.get() == 0 and varak.get() == 0 and varab.get() == 0:

                for i, b, z in zip(df['CId'], df['PId'], df['NewStartDate']):
                cd['startDate'] = re.sub('^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', str(z),
                cd['startDate'])

                pd['pricingSchedule']['startDate'] = re.sub('^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}',
                cd['startDate'], pd['pricingSchedule']['startDate'])
                Few more bits

            elif varsd.get() == 1 and varad.get() == 0 and vared.get() == 0 and varcn.get() == 0
            and varpn.get() == 0 and varak.get() == 0 and varab.get() == 0:

               for i, b, z in zip(df['CId'], df['PId'], df['NewStartDate']):
               cd['startDate'] = re.sub('^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', str(z),
               cd['startDate'])
               Few more bits
```

Comment: From what you write here, it is hard to tell what exactly you are trying. If you would add a piece of code of what you already have, we could much better help you.

Comment: You probably need to give an example of what is happening inside the `if` blocks, that way it will be easier to help determine if there is a way to simplify

Comment: Does that help at all?

Comment: are you wanting to do 128 different things based on the values or do certain checkboxes have meaning? it would be really helpful to know what the checkboxes do because your current code tells us nothing. Go write a minimal verifiable complete example and come back when youve done that

Comment: So it's still not entirely clear if you have some logic involving the particular checkboxes which is consistent in determining what occurs in the `if` blocks. e.g. Does having `varad.get() ==  1` always mean you do the `pricingSchedule` bit? One thing I would probably do straight away is create tuple at the top like `cboxes = (varsd.get(), varad.get(), vared.get(), varcn.get(), varpn.get(), varak.get(), varab.get())` and then use that in any if statement like so: `if cboxes == (1,1,0,0,0,0,0)`

Comment: Want to do 128 different things based on the values. All the boxes basically just use regex to change values from a block of JSON. One box if checked will update the start date, one box if checked will update the end date, one box if checked will update the C Name, one box will update the P Name

Comment: It sounds like you just need 7 consecutive if statements where each if statement is run if its corresponding tickbox is selected

Comment: The tuples is a great idea, thank for that PyPingu. Yes maybe I am over complicating this dangee1705

Comment: Maybe use a state machine?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if-else ladder`, why don't you use `nested if` statements?
Like

```
if a:
  if b:
    if c:
      ...
    else:
      ... 
  else:
    ... 
else:
  ...
```